# Bootstrap modal not showing (but the page is getting darker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and I need to trigger it inside a javascript function. Here is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sMail == 202) {
        $('#contato').modal('show');
    } else if (sMail != 0) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

and my modal

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true" id="contato">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when the function is executed, the page goes a little darker, just like when modals are open, but it doesn't show it :(

It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/jyax9d3f/1/ and also works with a button.

Comment: do you have this published anywhere?

Comment: @SethMcClaine no :(

Comment: try putting the code in question in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap) and see if you end up with the same issue... if you do publish it and post the link here. it will help us tell what you're running into

Comment: Well, it is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/jyax9d3f/1/

Comment: So it is likely you have css, or JS elsewhere in your code that is preventing you from getting it to show

Comment: Here with a button... https://jsfiddle.net/ajv93byw/

Comment: We would need additional code to debug.

Comment: Most likely css

Comment: I have modals in a different page and it works fine being triggered by a button. The only modal who doesn't work is this one, that I need to trig using js :(

Comment: throw a debugger in your code and confirm that `sMail` is `202` and see if you can trigger the modal from the console

Comment: It is `202`, I have a `console.log` in `sMail`. I also can't trigger the modal from the console, nothing happens when I try to

Comment: That, again, points to the likelihood of either additional JS or CSS that is interfering. We most likely wont be able to assist without additional view into the code. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using alert instead of modal.